# Why does this covering index query performs better when paginating far away from beginning?

Tags: mysql, performance

While reading "Optimizing Sorts" section of "High Performance MySQL 2nd Edition", I find it hard to understand the following:

> **mysql> SELECT  FROM profiles WHERE sex='M' ORDER BY rating LIMIT 100000, 10;**
>
> Such queries can be a serious problem no matter how they’re indexed, because the
>   high offset requires them to spend most of their time scanning a lot of data that they
>   will then throw away.
>   ...
>   Another good strategy for optimizing such queries is to use a covering index to
>   retrieve just the primary key columns of the rows you’ll eventually retrieve. ... Here’s an example that requires an index on(sex, rating)to work efficiently:
>
> **mysql>SELECT (cols) FROM profiles INNER JOIN (**
>     **-> SELECT (primary key cols) FROM profiles**
>     **-> WHERE x.sex='M' ORDER BY rating LIMIT 100000, 10**
>     **->) AS x USING(primary key cols);**

My question is, if the first query cant utilize (sex rating) index to find rows 100000-100010, how would the second query do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From "High Performance MySQL 2nd Edition"

> Such queries can be a serious problem no matter how they’re indexed,
>   because the high offset requires them to spend most of their time
>   scanning a lot of data that they will then throw away. **Denormalizing,
>   precomputing, and caching are likely to be the only strategies that
>   work for queries like this one.** An even better strategy is to limit
>   the number of pages you let the user view. This is unlikely to impact
>   the user’s experience, because no one really cares about the 10,000th
>   page of search results.
>
> Another good strategy for optimizing such queries is to use a covering
>   index to retrieve just the primary key columns of the rows you’ll
>   eventually retrieve. You can then join this back to the table to
>   retrieve all desired columns. This helps minimize the amount of work
>   **MySQL must do gathering data that it will only throw away**.

It has been stated that there is no better improvement to this query. It just suggest that to minimize number selected of columns just to `index` column (of course to save memory of storing all the data of all columns of 10,0000 rows to store only index column of 10,000 rows during the scan process). Then use the 10 retrieved index to construct the full columns.